# How to use a variable value from another class?

Tags: java

How do i get firstname variable in the detailgrouping class to be the input from firstname in the name class?
Thank you for any advice and just trying to understand.

```
class maine {
    public static void main (String args []){       
        name nameObject = new name ();
        detailgrouping detailObject = new detailgrouping(); 

        nameObject.usernames ();
        detailObject.collect ();

     }
}
import java.util.Scanner
public class name {
    public void usernames (){
        Scanner scnkey =new Scanner (System.in);    
        System.out.println("Users first name"); 
        String firstname = scnkey.nextLine();   
        System.out.println("Users last name");  
        String lastname = scnkey.nextLine();
    }
}

public class detailgrouping {
    public void collect (){ 
        System.out.println(" Users first name: " + firstname);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, what is `detailObject` and where did it come from? It wasn't there some revisions ago.

Comment: now that the code is formatted and readable, a better question is, how does the firstname variable get into the detailgrouping class in the first place. looks to me like you have an undefined variable there.

Comment: Yes sorry. I included it in an edit. there is many more classes but i just included these ones to let me have idea for the other similar classes.

Comment: Take a moment and make a good edit that deals with any missing parts and make sure it will compile. You're missing a `detailgrouping` declaration.

Comment: Thanks ..missed that. but how do i get

System.out.println(" Users first name: " + firstname); 

TO use the input for firstname in name class

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> public class name {    String firstname;
> public void usernames (){
>     Scanner scnkey =new Scanner (System.in);    
>     System.out.println("Users first name"); 
>      firstname = scnkey.nextLine();   
>     System.out.println("Users last name");  
>     String lastname = scnkey.nextLine();
> } 
>   }
>
> public class detailgrouping extends name {
> public void collect (){ 
>     System.out.println(" Users first name: " + firstname);
> } }
> ```

This will work

Comment: thank you but
I ran that and the ouput is reading 

Users first name: null

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your 'DetailGrouping' class wants to access your 'Name' class, and 'Maine' is the launcher using both these classes.
If you want to access vars in which you are storing user input values, you probably should create member variables of class 'Name' along with its getter/setter. Your code should throw compile time error atm, stating 'firstname' variable is not declared in class 'DetailGrouping'. You may also want to check the scope/boundaries of method execution. Your vars dont exist outside of the method that they are declared in.

The working code is :

```
Package myPackage;
import java.util.Scanner;


class name {
    String firstname, lastname;
    public void usernames (){
        Scanner scnkey =new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Users first name");
        firstname = scnkey.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Users last name");
        lastname = scnkey.nextLine();
    }
}

class detailgrouping {
    public void collect (name obj){
        System.out.println(" Users first name: " + obj.firstname);
    }
}

class maine{
    public static void main (String args []){
        name nameObject = new name ();
        detailgrouping detailObject = new detailgrouping();

        nameObject.usernames ();
        detailObject.collect (nameObject);

    }
}
```